# What does ggf reserviert mean on DB trains?

Tags: trains, germany

On some seats it says 'ggf. reserviert'. What does this mean? Can I sit in the seat?

Answer (score 33):

“ggf.” stands for *gegebenenfalls* or “possibly”. It means the seat has been set aside in the railway booking system for last minute reservations. The official website recommends [not sitting there](https://www.bahn.de/faq/auf-welchen-plaetzen-kann-ich-mich-einchecken) because it may actually be reserved. In practice, you can sit there without trouble as long as you are willing leave the seat if someone does show up with a reservation (this is actually [one of the tips](https://www.stuttgarter-zeitung.de/gallery.tipps-und-tricks-fuers-bahnfahren-wie-sie-fast-immer-einen-sitzplatz-bekommen-auch-ohne-reservierung.832a5f30-fe5f-4b56-8b66-7aef6abdbe37.html) to find an empty seat I found on a local newspaper's website). By contrast, there are also usually seats where the display is empty and those are definitely not reserved.

Comment: +1, though I wouldn't say that you can _usually_ find seats where the display is empty. YMMV, but more often than not, by the time I enter a train, all those seats are already occupied.

Comment: Are these seats "blocked" (ie. I cannot click on them to choose them during my reservation)? Or I can still choose them but risk being kicked off by someone who reserved later than me (this would be wild)

Comment: @WoJ if it lets you reserve them (and you get a confirmation of that reservation), then you are the one who's doing the reserving

Comment: Thanks and can you clarify, 'free' there means not 'at no charge' but merely 'not reserved'?

Comment: @Sabine I meant there are seats like that in the train, to highlight the meaning of “ggf. reserviert”, not that you would find them empty. But to be honest, I am not even sure there are always non-reservable seats in each and every train, even if I read somewhere that it is indeed the case (hence the "usually").

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I meant “not reserved” indeed. They might obviously be occupied and you cannot reserve them for free.

Comment: Can you clarify any of that? 

'there are seats like that in the train' does not highlight the meaning of “ggf. reserviert” and 'Not that you would find them empty' adds only confusion.

Why might there be non-reservable seats on any train? 'First come, first served'

When you meant ' “not reserved”… They might… be occupied and you cannot reserve them for free' why not make that clear?

'You cannot reserve them for free…' would mean 'at no cost.'

In complete contrast 'You cannot reserve them; they're free…' has nothing to do with cost… in no way comparable.

Which did you mean?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I edited the answer before you wrote your last comment, is it still unclear? It seems you're quoting my comments but not the answer. Even though English is more ambiguous than German or French in this respect, I didn't feel I needed to clarify the meaning of free because you can never reserve a seat at no cost. Is that what's confusing you?

Comment: As to why there might be non-reservable seats, I have no idea, because the DB wants it so? Unlike the other answer, I was trying not to speculate on the reasons why as it's hard to find solid info on that. They could probably guess how many seats are likely to be reserved, add some buffer, mark them as “ggf. reserviert” and leave the others open? By the time the displays are updated, they certainly don't need to block each and every seat. But I also read online that they never open more than 70% of seats to reservation, which may or may not be true.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Rereading your comment, I am even more confused. "You cannot reserve them for free…" indeed means "at no cost" because you raised that possibility and seemed to ask about it. That sentence was however never part of the answer, where the word “free” just means “not reserved”. So which it is depends on the context, which is not possible to avoid with the word “free” in English.

Comment: In fact, after I took all the earlier comments into account but before you wrote your last one (40 minutes ago), the answer did not contain the word “free” anymore. I suggest reading it again with an open mind instead of trying to argue with past comments, the meaning should hopefully become clear and answer all your questions.

Comment: Good for you and I suggest getting real. If anyone minds whether 'free' was originally or is now in the actual wording of the Question, I hope that one will speak up now…

Please ask yourself whether what you meant in German really equates to what you said in English?

Until then why not accept that 'ggf. reserviert' seems to translate to something closely like 'provisionally reserved'?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Pointing out ambiguity and suggesting improvements is what comments are for so that's great but if we want to get real, do you find anything unclear *about the answer itself*? Doesn't it answer all your questions and if not, what do you still need clarified? “Provisionally reserved” does not seem like a bad translation, what makes you think this is something I need to “accept”? Incidentally, I didn't mean anything “in German”, which isn't my native language.

Comment: If you'd rather go to Chat, please do. Until then, please explain how, eg, dropping 'free' was a legitimate move anywhere but in a fight, as clearly opposed to a search for knowledge?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148304/discussion-between-relaxed-and-robbie-goodwin).

Comment: The sentence is actually funny because the literal meaning is "it is reserved if that is the case". Wittgenstein could not agree more ;-).

Answer (score 7):

It says that the seat may be reserved, but that at the time of departure (when the reservations were loaded) it wasn't. This because people can still reserve seats after the train has already started its service.

Comment: Does this mean if nothing shows on the display it is impossible for that seat to become reserved? Are there fewer reservations available than free seats?

Comment: @Tom [The Man in Seat 61](https://www.seat61.com/train-travel-in-germany.htm) says "**ggf. reserviert** - _this means the train's on-board reservation system hasn't been updated with the latest information from the main DB reservation system.  Usually all of the seats show this message if this happens.  Seat reservations are still valid, but cannot be shown on the LED displays, so you can sit in these seats but you could be asked to move if someone shows up with a reservation_.

Comment: I am seeing it on a train that I am now which does have valid reservations on other seats

Comment: You can sit in that seat if you accept that someone might come with a valid reservation and send you away.

Comment: @Tom Yes, exactly, not all seats are available for reservation and only a limited contingent is held for last minute reservations so if there is nothing on the display, the seat is definitely free.

Comment: @Tom The Man in Seat 61 is wrong with the statement, that usually all seats show the message if this happens. For example, if there's a train from Hamburg to Munich, all reservations that have been made by the time the train leaves Hamburg will show as regular reservations. The seats with "ggf. freigeben" are for those passengers that want to travel e.g. from Nuremberg to Munich and book a seat during the five hours when the train has already left Hamburg but not reached Nuremberg yet.

Comment: @Sabine The Man in Seat 61 is actually right. Not all trains are able to receive OTA updates of the reservation system, so the conductor has to load the reservation information into the system manually. The system then tells the displays what to show. If the conductor fails to load the information into the system (or the system is unavailable), all displays fall back to a predefined message, which is "ggf. reserviert".
However, you're correct on pointing out that seats which can be reserved after the train departed its first stop are shown as "ggf. reserviert" too.

Comment: The problem is that I have never seen a sign saying "nicht reserviert". It seems that _all_ seats that aren't reserved already show that "ggf. reserviert" message, which makes it basically impossible to find a seat if you don't have a reservation.

Comment: @PMF Well, that is the point of having a reservation vs. not having a reservation, isn't it? Finding a seat that is empty *at that time* does not mean it couldn't be reserved *for a later leg of the journey*. You enter the train in Hannover, find an unreserved seat, train leaves the station. Someone in Nuremberg then reserves your seat for Nuremberg -- Munich. (Because that seat is not reserved just because you are sitting in it right now.) So you might have a seat until Nuremberg, or perhaps Munich, who knows. You didn't reserve, did you? Why should you have a right to that seat, or any seat?

Comment: @DevSolar That's the view of the railway company,  as they earn something on reservations. But I do have a valid ticket and reservations are not mandatory. So if the train has plenty of free seats (OK, that's rare on the ICE), I would expect the reservations to pick seats in a certain order.

Comment: @PMF Reservations can be for a window seat or an aisle seat, a table seat, a cabin seat, and / or a no-phone seat, and the railway company is not interested in jamming all reserved seats together at one end of the waggon, might it be that you just don't *see* the certain order they are placing those reservations? You hold a valid ticket, so you are entitled to transport. You, however, are arguing for getting the comfort of a reservation -- actually, *more* comfort as you want to *choose* your seat -- without paying for it. Doesn't take a railway company person to smell the entitlement there.